# Consuming Multiple resources from a single REST Service

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing a Spring Boot Application which consumes another REST service to get the User's Account information. The same service provides multiple operations like:

*GET*: /userid/retrive -to get user and account information

*POST*: /user/create  - to create a new user

*POST*: /userid/save - to save the user information

*DELETE*: /userid - to remove the user information from the system

*POST*: /userid/account : to update account information

...

So All the above apis are exposed by one service. Some of them return the same response object while others do not and each of them have their own request parameters and request headers that should be set before calling.

So what I have done is I have created a Base class which will have the common code and I have extended it for One Rest template per API operation which will set its own request parameters and call the service and also has different exception loggers/messages.

The service also exposes other operations which we start consuming in our upcoming sprints, and I wanted to make sure if we can utilize any existing design pattern for our advantage.

So I am writing this question to know if there are any alternatives or any design patterns you could suggest so as calling the same service would not have multiple rest templates.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create one interface per resource, which has all the resource's operations:

```
interface UserResource {
  getUserAccountInformation();

  create(User);

  saveUserInfo(UserInfo)

  remove()

  update(UserInfo)
}
```

You can then have another interface which is basically represents a client for the other API:

```
interface SomeClient {
  UserResource user();
}
```

How you then implement this, is up to you, but no matter the implementation, the calls will always look like this:

```
client.user().someOp();
```

You can then refactor the implementation to have a base class, one class per operation, etc. But the refactorings would not have any effect on the users of the client.

When you will be adding additional resources to the client, you will just add the resource to SomeClient interface, in the same way as it is done with the UserResource.

Main point being - if other people will be dependent on your code, they will see a pretty interface and not care how it is implemented. You will then be able to change it however you want and noone will notice unless you break something, which is a the best you can hope for.

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer***
*I have no experience with Spring Boot. This question seems to focus on REST in general, so my answer is focused as such. If the context of Spring Boot invalidates this answer; let me know and I will remove it.*

---

Firstly, REST is a guideline to design your API interface. It doesn't quite care how you write the concrete implementation of that guideline. As an extreme example, you could dump all of your application's endpoints into a single code file while at the same time being REST-compliant if all endpoints follow the correct resource format.

Secondly, while the REST specification is written quite clearly, in practice there is some leeway as to how pure you implement it. There is no universal answer to the question of how pure your REST implementation must be, because every scenario has its own reasons for being the way it is.

If REST purity is high on your priority list, then by all means pursue it. But there are also plenty of cases where pursuing purity is a futile effort when you already have a working clean codebase which simply uses a slightly different interface from what REST prescribes.

Using pure REST, your endpoints are not correct.

- `GET: /userid/retrive` should be `GET: /user/{userId}`
- `POST: /user/create` should be `POST: /user`
- `POST: /userid/save` (I assume this is the update) should be `PUT: /user/{userId}`
- `DELETE: /userid` should be `DELETE: /user/{userId}` (I assume this one is correct but you did not mention the `/user` part of the URL)

`POST: /userid/account` could mean one of two things. If the account details are part of the user, this should be `PATCH: /user/{userId}`.

If the account details are a separate entity, then `/user/{userId}/account` is considered to be a separate REST resource (with its own `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, ...).

It can sometimes make sense to structure one REST resource to fall under another. This is again a purity argument. In pure DDD and REST; each aggregate root is self-contained and it doesn't make sense to nest one REST resource in another. However, in the real world we often have to make practical trade-offs (e.g. for performance reasons) which steers us away from purity for the sake of purity.

While REST doesn't quite care how you structure your concrete implementation (as mentioned before); in the latter case good practice would commonly dictate that the account detail resource then lives in its own controller/service.

> Some of them return the same response object while others do not

While it's relatively common for a REST resource to use the same DTO structure for all of its operations, exceptions do exist, e.g. in cases where the update is not allowed to update every field. Audit fields are a good example here.

I am unsure whether having different DTO structures here violates pure REST or not, but given the fact that in reality most REST implementations are less than 100% pure anyway, I think this is an exercise in labeling more so than actual development design. If it makes sense for your use case; then do it. Adhering to your requirements is more important than striving for REST purity as a matter of principle alone.

> and each of them have their own request parameters and request headers that should be set before calling.

It is unclear to me precisely what this entails or how you came to implement this. In regard to the request parameters, I refer to my previous point of the requirements being more important than purity for the sake of principle. In regards to the request headers, I'm not quite sure why you need that.

> The service also exposes other operations which we start consuming in our upcoming sprints, and I wanted to make sure if we can utilize any existing design pattern for our advantage.

By other operations, what do you mean?

If you mean different resources (e.g. `/company/{companyId}` with its own `GET`, `POST`, ...), then this is just a different resource just like `/user/{userId}/account` already was.

If you mean operations such as e.g. `/user/{userId}/sendEmail` to send an email to the user; this is a [remote procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). This is something that is beyond pure REST. REST is resource-oriented, whereas RPC is action-oriented.

It's perfectly okay to have RPC in your codebase when you need it; but it just doesn't fall under the REST moniker; and there's no point in trying to fish for REST compliance here as it is simply a completely unrelated concept. This is again a matter of requirements over purity.

> So what I have done is I have created a Base class which will have the common code and I have extended it for One Rest template per API operation which will set its own request parameters and call the service and also has different exception loggers/messages.

As mentioned before, REST does not dictate your concrete implementation. It's perfectly okay to have a base controller class from which all your controllers derive, with the purpose of promoting reusability for the controller-related logic.

As a matter of good practice, try to ensure that this base controller is resource-agnostic, and only contains shared *controller* logic. I can't judge your code since you didn't post it, this is only meant as a reminder.

> So I am writing this question to know if there are any alternatives or any design patterns you could suggest so as calling the same service would not have multiple rest templates.

Just to repeat: since REST does not dictate the concrete implementation, there is no right/wrong here (at least according to REST itself).

In practice, I would suggest grouping all of the endpoints belonging to a single resource into a single controller, rather than having a controller for each single resource endpoint. In your example, I would advocate for having two controllers, one for `User` and one for `Account` (I am assuming here that we took the route where the account details are a separate entity from the user itself).

That being said, there's nothing *wrong* about separating your resource endpoints entirely. I'm just questioning whether it's meaningful or necessary to do so. I have yet to see a compelling reason why a single REST resource's endpoint cannot live in the same controller, since their implementation is usually very terse (it should merely map the request and pass the buck to the underlying service).